# Using @supports with styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components

I've recently switched to using [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) for my styling and I've been trying to get the @supports feature of CSS to work but with no luck.

The @supports syntax is used somewhat like:

```
@supports (display: grid) {
    .Container {
        background-color: orange;
    }
}
```

Now this is fine as the styled-components docs have the following line:

> **Note**: Ampersands (&) get replaced by our generated, unique classname for that styled component

But when I try using the ampersand to use this, it doesn't work. When using the below code I get an ampersand in the outputted CSS

```
const Container = styled.div`
    @supports (display: block) {
      & {
        background-color: seagreen;
      }
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a genuine bug in `styled-components`! You should not need to put the ampersand there at all, it should work just like media queries:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  @supports (display: block) {
    background-color: seagreen;
  }
`;
```

It doesn't right now though, so I've opened [an issue with our parser](https://github.com/thysultan/stylis.js/issues/16) and it should hopefully be resolved soon. I'll update this answer once it's fixed!

Comment: Thanks @maxstbr, I'll mark this as the correct answer once updated with a fix

Comment: @maxstbr, I had a look at the styled-components package.json and yarn.lock. Looks like stylis isn't being updated to latest version. It's stuck on 2.0.3.

Comment: Note for new readers: stylis has since been updated and `@supports` is now, well, supported! 